# ListProperty object is not iterable kivy

Tags: python, kivy

here my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from pieces.whitepawn import WhitePawn
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class CubeWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self,color,id,piece,**kwargs):
        self.id=id
        self.piece=piece
        self.color=ListProperty(color)
        super(CubeWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        if self.piece:
            self.img=Image(source=self.piece.source)
            self.add_widget(self.img)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x,touch.y):
            self.color=[1,1,0,1]
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```

associated .kv file

```
<CubeWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:root.color
                
        Rectangle:
            size:root.size

    
<New_Board>:
    rows:8
    cols:8
```

So, Basically i want is that when mouse is clicked(on_touch_down) then the widget color should changed.i dont get why it always says

**ListProperty object is not iterable**

for this line

```
rgba:root.color
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` should be defined outside of any method (poorly documented, but true). So your `color` should be defined like this:

```
class CubeWidget(RelativeLayout):
    # define Properties here
    color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])

    def __init__(self, color, id, piece, **kwargs):
        self.id=id
        self.piece=piece
        self.color=color  # set Property value
        super(CubeWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.piece:
            self.img=Image(source=self.piece.source)
            self.add_widget(self.img)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x,touch.y):
            self.color=[1,1,0,1]
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```